# Getting error Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, testng

I'm trying to run `TestNG` from command line, but it's giving me error.
Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

**java -cp C:/TestNG directory/testng-6.2.jar;C:\project directory\src\com\suites\suite\shop org.testng.TestNG testng.xml**

**Error**: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

My scripts runs fine when I ran them from `eclipse testng plugin`.

Answer (score 10):

1. Copy the below commands in a text file.
2. Edit the location.
3. Save it as **`yourtext.bat`**
4. Now, double click on the batch file created.

> **cd C:\Workspace\projectname**
>
> **java -cp C:\Workspace\projectname\lib*;C:\Workspace\projectname\bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml**

Comment: Awesome! Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Path of TestNG.jar file was not set up.
Follow instructions of following site to set up. It worked for me: 
http://qtp-automate.blogspot.com/2011/10/running-selenium-testng-test-from.html

Answer (score 2):

1. Try above answers.
2. If still not work, then you might have downloaded the wrong version of `testng.jar`. From link [testng.org](http://testng.org/doc/download.html), please click "here for ant users" to download a full testng.jar(11 mega bytes),   not a "Maven Central" version(no more than 100k).

I have tested those two versions on centos following [testng tutorial point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_environment.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Possibly your **testng.jar** file is not in the lib folder that `C:\Workspace\projectname\lib`.

You should find **testng.jar** first in your computer and move it manually to `C:\Workspace\projectname\lib`. Then it will work

Answer (score 1):

My Assumptions:

1. You are trying to run test file from command prompt
2. libs folder generated under Project/tagret upon using "mvn clean package -DskipTests"
3. class file generated under Project/target/test-classes/package-name

With above assumptions in mind, you can follow below process.

Setting class path in command prompt:

```
1. Open project location in command prompt


2. set classpath=C:\User\SeleniumTestProject\target\test-classes;C:\User\SeleniumTestProject\target\libs\*

3. java org.testng.TestNG C:\User\SeleniumTestProject\testng.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the lib folder contains testng-6.8.jar(or any other version) file because testng.xml even executes successfully without testng-6.8.jar (or any other version) with the jars that gets added when we add TestNG library.