# Could not find or load main class org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG - in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver, testng

I've tried to update Selenium webdriver version and now i cant run my tests because of following exception:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG

Environment on which it was working fine:

```
Selenium 2.53 jar
Webdriver 2.53.1
Java 7
```

Environment that rises an Error:

```
Selenium 3.5 jar
Webdriver 3.5
Java 8
```

I need to run it from eclipse, not commnd line

[image]

Comment: Clean your project and try again. it may help you.

Comment: This question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894938/getting-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-testng-testng

Answer (score 0):

Some points to check:

- Check your build path and make sure all required packages are present there.
- Make sure your build path does not contain any redundant packages
- Check for packages compatibility
- Eventually move out from the manual packages managing and let Maven do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Always Try to use the latest version of TestNG:
From Properties>TestNG>

> You can uncheck the box called "Use project TestNG jar"

Date-19-June-2019

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.testng</groupId>
<artifactId>testng</artifactId>
<version>6.14.3</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```