# Running .bat file in selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins, testng

My bat file is :

```
set projectLocation=C:\Users\admin\eclipse-workspace\Jenkins
cd %projectLocation%
set classpath=%projectLocation%\bin;%projectLocation%\lib\*
java org.testng.TestNG %projectLocation%\TestNG.xml
pause
```

I am running my .bat file but while executing bat file It shows error messgae

```
E:\Software\eclipse-java-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64\eclipse>java
org.testng.TestNG C:\Users\admin\eclipse-workspace\Jenkins\TestNG.xml
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

E:\Software\eclipse-java-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64\eclipse>pause Press
any key to continue . . .
```

Please anyone help

Comment: This is related to `TestNG`, why is `selenium` and `selenium-webdriver` tagged in this this question?

Comment: @DebanjanB because perhaps he is trying to run some selenium script that he wrote in eclipse using testNG.

Comment: @Alok That's fine as a info. But the actual Question have no linkage with `Selenium`. Mismatching of hash tags have the following impacts 1) Receive broader answers from unrelated tag experts (i.e. `Selenium`) 2) Tag experts of the real problem (i.e. `Python`) restrains from Answering due to `Selenium Dependency`

Comment: @DebanjanB completely agree. Thanks.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894938/getting-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-testng-testng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894938/getting-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-testng-testng) Hope this helps.