# Facing Jenkins error when try to run a selenium script batch file

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am facing the below error when try to run my batch file for a selenium script:

Started by user Jeyanthi Meena
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Users\jeyan\eclipse-workspace\PropineTest2
[PropineTest2] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\jeyan\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins9118461495074787504.bat

C:\Users\jeyan\eclipse-workspace\PropineTest2>run.bat

C:\Users\jeyan\eclipse-workspace\PropineTest2>cd C:\Users\jeyan\eclipse-workspace\PropineTest2

C:\Users\jeyan\eclipse-workspace\PropineTest2>java -cp C:\Users\jeyan\eclipse-workspace\PropineTest2\lib*;C:\Users\jeyan\eclipse-workspace\PropineTest2\bin org.testng.TestNG DateParseJava.xml
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894938/getting-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-testng-testng)

Comment: nope I tried but still getting same error